# Where is the bootstrap class?

Tags: angular

Beginner question. I am stuck with a tutorial which was written for the beta version of Angular 2. It is part of an online course. I am supposed to add `Routing` to the app so it will be available in all components. The tutorial says that I should add it to **boot.ts,** but there is no such file. Should I create it?

Here is what is supposed to be in boot.ts:

```
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import {AppComponent} from './app.component'

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

Obviously this is for the beta version. Where is the `bootstrap` class in the final? Is it even how it works or the whole thing is deprecated now?

Comment: What tutorial? The code example you show is for a very old Angular version (<= Angular2 RC.5) There are enough examples out there. Please check the docs before asking a question https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cli-quickstart.html

Comment: I did, but I don't even know where to look. The tutorial is Mosh Hamedani's course on udemy.com. It is a very good course, and he added guides on breaking changes, but sometimes it's incomplete.

Comment: http:angular.io contains a lot of Plunker links, every one of them contains a full running example and shows how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please take a look at Documentation page (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/setup.html)

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

or using Angular CLI instead (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli), this is official development tool for Angular.

btw, i think the Documentation page has lot more useful than your online course, because the content of this course seem outdated.

And for beginner, using Angular CLI is recommended.